# Angular 6 - Does it make a difference where you put the [formGroup]="form"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

Working in Angular 6 and I'm seeing some pages where we have:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
```

and others where it is:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
```

Does it make any difference where the formGroup directive is placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the directive **FormGroup**, it doesn't really matter, you can use a reactive form with either of these.

But if you intend to use `ngSubmit`, you'd have to use `<form [formGroup]="form">` because it wouldn't work with `<div [formGroup]="form">`